# jQuery Javascript adds an extra row to the table in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, model-view-controller

I have a main view which has a "Comments" link on each row that when clicked it opens up a partial view. The partial view displays a table and textboxes, and an "Add" button that when clicked it adds the data entered in the textboxes to the table.

The first time I click on comments, I add data to the textboxes and hit the Add button and everything works.

The problem is:  when I open the partial view from another record(by clicking on Comments) and add data to the textboxes, after I click on add it adds an extra blank row.  It is as if the add button is clicked twice.  Could you please help me solve this issue?  The code I am using is below. I also attached pics.
Thank you very much.

**PARTIAL VIEW:**

```
    @model IEnumerable<HelpDeskSupport.Models.Comment>

    <html>
    <body>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="1500" id="tblComments">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TicketNumber)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Comment1)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AssignedTo)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CreatedBy)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date)
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TicketNumber)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Comment1)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AssignedTo)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedBy)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtTicketNumber" value=@ViewData["NumberFromViewAll"] readonly /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtComment" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtAssignedTo" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtCreatedBy" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtDate" /></td>
            <td><input type="button" id="btnAddComment" value="Add" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
<br />
<input type="button" id="btnSave" value="Save All" />

@*<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>*@
<script src="~/Scripts/json2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("body").on("click", "#btnAddComment", function () {
        //Reference the TextBoxes
        var txtTicketNumber = $("#txtTicketNumber");
        var txtComment = $("#txtComment");
        var txtAssignedTo = $("#txtAssignedTo");
        var txtCreatedBy = $("#txtCreatedBy");
        var txtDate = $("#txtDate");

        //Get the reference of the Table's TBODY element
        var tableBody = $("#tblComments > TBODY")[0];
        //Add Row
        var row = tableBody.insertRow(-1);

        //Add TicketNumber cell          
        var cell = $(row.insertCell(-1));
        cell.html(txtTicketNumber.val());

        //Add Comment cell
        cell = $(row.insertCell(-1));
        cell.html(txtComment.val());

        //Add AssignedTo cell
        cell = $(row.insertCell(-1));
        cell.html(txtAssignedTo.val());

        //Add CreatedBy cell
        cell = $(row.insertCell(-1));
        cell.html(txtCreatedBy.val());

        //Add Date cell
        cell = $(row.insertCell(-1));
        cell.html(txtDate.val());           

        //Clear the TextBoxes
        txtComment.val("");
        txtAssignedTo.val("");
        txtCreatedBy.val("");
        txtDate.val("");
    });

    $("body").on("click", "#btnSave", function () {
        //Loop through the Table rows and build a JSON array
        var commentsArray = new Array();
        $("#tblComments TBODY TR").each(function () {
            var row = $(this);
            var commentLine = {};
            commentLine.TicketNumber = row.find("TD").eq(0).html();
            commentLine.Comment1 = row.find("TD").eq(1).html();
            commentLine.AssignedTo = row.find("TD").eq(2).html();
            commentLine.CreatedBy = row.find("TD").eq(3).html();
            commentLine.Date = row.find("TD").eq(4).html();
            commentsArray.push(commentLine);
        });

        //Send the JSON array to Controller using AJAX
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Tickets/InsertComments",
            data: JSON.stringify(commentsArray),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function () {
                alert("Comment(s) inserted.");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
     //VIEW ALL COMMENTS AND DISPLAY IN PARTIAL
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ViewComments(int ticketNum)
    {
        List<Comment> AllComments = new List<Comment>();
        using (DBModel db = new DBModel())
            AllComments = db.Comments.Where(x => x.TicketNumber == ticketNum).ToList();

        //get iNumber from ViewAll to display in the ticket number textbox of the comments partial view
        ViewData["NumberFromViewAll"] = ticketNum;

        return PartialView("ViewComments", AllComments);
    }

    public JsonResult InsertComments(List<Comment> commentsArray)
    {
        using (DBModel db = new DBModel())
        {
            if (commentsArray != null)
            {
                var lastColumnComments = commentsArray.Last();
                var ticketNumberToDelete = lastColumnComments.TicketNumber;
                var sqlQuery = "Delete [Comments] where TicketNumber = " + ticketNumberToDelete;
                //Delete all comments from comments table. Previous comments are copied in javascript and re-populated
                db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sqlQuery);
            }

            //Check for NULL
            //if (commentsArray == null)
            //{
            //    commentsArray = new List<Comment>();
            //}

            foreach (Comment c in commentsArray)
            {
                db.Comments.Add(c);
            }               
            int insertedRecords = db.SaveChanges();
            return Json(insertedRecords);
        }
    }
```

**IN CASE YOU WANT TO SEE HOW THE VIEWCOMMENTS IS DISPLAYED FROM THE MAIN VIEW:**

```
  @section modalComments
{
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showComments() {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            title: "View Details"
        });
        $("#ticketTable .details").click(function () {
            var ticketNum = $(this).closest("tr").find("td").eq(0).html();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Tickets/ViewComments",
                data: '{ticketNum: "' + ticketNum + '" }',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#dialog').html(response);
                    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
    };

    $(function () {
        showComments();
    });
```

[image: Main View]

[image: Comments View]

Comment: I think, ViewComments is invoked twice after "saveComments" happen. Please have breakpoints and debug.

Comment: By debugging it looks like the add button runs twice, but that happens not the first time around instead when I click on another Comments link and try to add.  So it is for the save all button as it saves the same thing to the database twice.  Could anyone suggest what code changes I should make?  I cannot seem to see the error.  Thank you very much.